# When is one or more PDEs equivalent to one or more ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm relatively new to PDEs and ODEs. It seems that PDEs are generally more difficult to solve than ODEs, and so I intuitively have the feeling that one needs more information/knowledge/theorems in order to solve PDEs.

I've seen many examples of going from from the ODE domain to the PDE domain, and vice versa. For example, I could set up an infinite series of ODEs that model an infinite line of masses connected by springs. Then one could, loosely speaking, get the wave equation (a PDE) when letting the mass go to density. Or, FEM approximates a PDE as a finite set of ODEs, but by letting each element go to zero size, one could regain the original PDE.

Vice versa, the method of characteristics, or the method of separation of variables, allows one to rewrite a PDE as a (finite) set of ODEs.

I'm wondering if there are general, perhaps hand-wavy, arguments for when it is possible to do such transformations?

I feel that the PDE has to be sufficiently simple, or we need to know some additional information about the solution, in order to rewrite it to ODEs. Likewise I am guessing that only infinite sets of ODEs can be written as PDEs, but I am not sure if all infinite sets of ODEs are equivalent to a PDE.

Comment: Mainly if $n=1$. Partial derivatives show up if there are more than one dimension. They only describe the linear approximation along their coordinate line, while the function varies over several variables so that the Jacobian matrix is needed (thus linear approximations along all coordinates) to describe the linear approximation. Partial derivatives are weaker constraints on the possible solutions than ordinary total derivatives.

Comment: It is difficult to say something about all PDEs in general because the field is so diverse. Different types of equations have different interpretations and properties (compare hyperbolic and elliptic equations). Rather than that one usually studies certain types of equations.